# Insert and update text into sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a page that seems to work fine other than updating new text to the database. Everytime I hit submit it just takes it back to the original data. Please let me know what is missing for this to successfully query old data and update new data.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "Update Load")
{
    for ($count = 1; $count <= 6; $count++)
    {
        $fields[$count] = "";
        if (isset($_POST["field" . $count . ""]))
        {
            $fields[$count] = trim($_POST["field" . $count . ""]);
            //echo $fields[$count] . "<br />";
        }
    }

    $con = mysql_connect("", "", "");
    mysql_select_db("", $con);

    $carriername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['carriername']);
    $contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $rating = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rating']);
    $info = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['info']);



    $insert = "UPDATE carrierinfo Set `carriername` = '$carriername', `contact` = '$contact', `phone` = '$phone', `rating` = '$rating', `info` = '$info'  WHERE `id` = '$id';";
    mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

    $select = "SELECT `carriername` ,`contact` ,`phone` ,`rating` ,`info` ,`id` FROM `carrierinfo` ORDER BY `carriername` DESC;";
    $result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
}
 if ($rating == "")
    {
    $rating = "3";
    }
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $con = mysql_connect("", "", "");
    mysql_select_db("", $con);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
    $select = "SELECT * FROM `carrierinfo` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
    $fields = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
    mysql_close($con);
}
else
{
    header("Location:board.php");
}
?>
</script>
<style ="text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div
 style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 16px 20px 20px; width: 400px; background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216); text-align: center; float: left;">
<form action="" method="post";">
  <div
  style="margin: 8px auto auto; width: 300px; font-family: arial; text-align: left;"><br>
  <table style="font-weight: normal; width: 100%; font-size: 12px;"
 border="1" bordercolor="#929087" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
   <table
 style="font-weight: normal; width: 100%; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;"
 border="1" bordercolor="#929087" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Carrier Name:</td><td><input id="carriername" name="carriername" maxlength="50" style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="<?php echo $fields[carriername]; ?>">
                    </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Contact:</td><td><input id="contact" name="contact" maxlength="50" style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="<?php echo $fields[contact]; ?>">
                    </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Phone:</td><td><input id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="50" style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="<?php echo $fields[phone]; ?>">
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%;">Carrier Rating:</td><td>
              <select id="rating" name="rating">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option <?php if($fields[rating] == "1") echo "selected"; ?> value="1">1</option>
              <option <?php if($fields[rating] == "2") echo "selected"; ?> value="2">2</option>
              <option <?php if($fields[rating] == "3") echo "selected"; ?> value="3">3</option>
              <option <?php if($fields[rating] == "4") echo "selected"; ?> value="4">4</option>
              <option <?php if($fields[rating] == "5") echo "selected"; ?> value="5">5</option>
              </select>
              </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%;">Carrier Info:</td><td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><textarea name="info" maxlength="65535"  style="width: 100%; height: 4em;"><?php echo $fields[info]; ?></textarea></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><input name="submit" value="Update"
 class="submit" type="submit"></p>
  </div>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='test3.php';" value="Back" />
</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: -20px;">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$insert = "UPDATE carrierinfo Set `carriername` = '$carriername', `contact` = '$contact', `phone` = '$phone', `rating` = '$rating', `info` = '$info'  **WHERE `id` = '$id';**";
```

You haven't declared what $id should be before running your UPDATE query so nothing is being updated.

Comment: If I want to keep it the same id? What should I put there. This page only opens with an exsiting id to "get"

Comment: Then set `$id = $_GET['id']` before you run your UPDATE query. Right now, you're setting it (if it isset) after you run your UPDATE query; you need to set it before.

Comment: That was it. I just didnt have it in the section. Thanks!

Comment: One more small issue.. I am trying to make rating defualt to the value 3 if nothing is selected. Its not doing it. See where I have my code. Any thoughts?

Comment: Same thing here, just move your `if($rating == "")` statement above your UPDATE query but make sure it's after your initial check of the $_POST['rating'].

Comment: Awesome... I figured.. just wanted a pro's opinion! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
$_POST["submit"] == "Update Load"
```

but the value of your submit button is "Update", not "Update Load".

Comment: I changed them to match and I get the same thing.